# In AWS VPC subnet id changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc, groups, rds

I deleted the default subnet in my VPC and tried to create new.

After creating the new subnet it showed a different subnet id, as you would expect.

When I try to create subnet group in RDS the same subnet shows the Default subnet's id that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ticket for AWS to fix.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer, I think the issue is more likely to be the description of the problem or the understanding of the person asking the question.

Comment: No, the only way to recreate the default subnet is to have AWS do it...

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that AWS need some time to delete the subnet from the infrastructure and you may need to give some time to make the change.

The next thing is make sure you are trying to create the RDS in the same region as the VPC that you make the subnet change.

Otherwise you need to make a ticket with AWS to resolve the issue because I'm out of ideas.